# Sheaves do not belong to algebraic geometry

Tags: sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topologies

In the n-cafe post https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/02/sheaves_do_not_belong_to_algeb.html Tom Leinster points out that sheaves on a topological space may be viewed in light of the nerve realization paradigm (the nerve realization adjunction induces an equivalence of Etalé spaces and sheaves). He also added a link to the latex file [http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/sheaves.pdf](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Etl/sheaves.pdf) where in the very end of the document Leinster asks the reader to generalize what has been done with sheaves on a top. space to sheaves on a grothendieck topology. I am somewhat stumped there, is there even a way to generalize this to Grothendieck topologies? I don't yet see an analogue for the poset of open subsets $\text{Open}(S)$ of a top. space $S$. Does someone have any further insights on this? :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sure Grothendieck topologies are generalizations of considerations of top. spaces and their open subsets/covers. Yet, this is not what I asked for I think. The nerve realization paradigm gives you an ajdunction between $\text{Psh}_{\text{Open}(S)}$ and $\text{Top}/S$. So if $\mathcal{C}$ is a site, how exactly does the corresponding nerve realization adjunction look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am somewhat stumped there, is there even a way to generalize this to Grothendieck topologies? I don't yet see an analogue for the poset of open subsets Open(S) of a top. space S.

The etale space construction for sites works in the same way as for topological spaces.

The etale space construction is a cocontinuous functor from sheaves to spaces, and cocontinuous functors from the category of sheaves of sets on a site $S$ can be identified with functors from $S$ such that covering sieves are mapped to isomorphisms.

If $S$ is the category of open subsets of a topological space $X$, then such a functor is given by sending $U\subset X$ to the map of topological spaces $U→X$.

If $S$ is an arbitrary site, one can supply such a functor manually.
In particular, we can specify a covering of the topos of sheaves of sets on $S$ by a localic topos (i.e., the topos of sheaves on a locale $L$),
and the inverse image functor $f^*$ sends an object $P∈S$ (interpreted as a map $P→1$) to an etale map of locales $f^*P→f^*1=L$, where sheaves of sets on $L$ are identified with their etale spaces.

Any Grothendieck topos admits a (nonunique) localic covering, so this construction always provides an etale space functor.

Comment: I see, is there any reference you can recommend where I can read up on this more?

Comment: @h3fr43nd: An even more general situation is discussed in Carchedi's paper [An étalé space construction for stacks](https://msp.org/agt/2013/13-2/p06.xhtml).